# Mass delete Debug logs in Salesforce

Tags: debugging, salesforce, apex, delete-row

In my developer sandbox the Apex logs count has exceeded beyond its limit and there are more than 100 000 records created in it. I want to mass delete them, but not able to do so.

I am using the windows machine, and tried running the below commands to achieve the same.

```
sfdx force:data:soql:query -q "SELECT Id FROM ApexLog" -r "csv" | out-file -encoding utf8 out.csv
sfdx force:data:bulk:delete -s ApexLog -f out.csv
```

But I am receiving an error in the console saying

> ERROR running force:data:bulk:delete:  InvalidBatch : Records not found

What am I doing wrong, and whether this can be achieved by any other way?

Comment: this should help: https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=code_debug_log_delete.htm&type=5

Answer (score 0):

While running the first command, giving the encoding parameter is of no use in this context, as the content is dumped with **UTF-8 BOM** encoding, not with **UTF-8**, there is a difference between the two.
I tried to find a way by which we can extract the data into UTF-8, but couldn't find anything related to this.

So you can run the following commands but need to change the encoding of the file manually with any editor.

```
sfdx force:data:soql:query -q "SELECT Id FROM ApexLog" -r "csv" > out.csv
//change the encoding of out.csv to UTF-8
sfdx force:data:bulk:delete -s ApexLog -f out.csv
```